# out of memory error with relatively few images in layout xml of android app

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am new to android development and am trying to build my gui using the layout xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0dp"
tools:context="com.fotovaultencryption.fraser.fotovault.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/main_background"
android:id="@+id/main_relative_layout">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/main_vertical_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header_iv"
        android:src="@drawable/header_btn"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/slogan_iv"
        android:src="@drawable/header_slogan"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/options_iv"
        android:src="@drawable/options_heading"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buttons_scroll_view" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_buttons_vertical_layout">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/take_photo_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/take_photo_btn"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/open_photo_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/open_photo_btn"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/decrypt_and_view_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/decrypt_and_view_btn"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/decrypt_and_save_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/decrypt_and_save_btn"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

None of the images are huge (the largest being the image used for the background of relative layout which is 800x1280 and 619kb) and there are only 8 on screen but I am using too much memory loading and scaling these images

Am I going about adding the buttons in the correct was or should I be doing it through code in my onCreate()? I have read alot about scaling my drawables and only saving the scaled versions to memory, but surely this then means I cannot create my ui through the xml layout file?

Comment: You can scale down the images when you load it in imageview in the activity.  you can use standard image loading library as well for easily scale down your images. Universal image loader will be good option. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1):

A 800x1280 image when rendered is 800 * 1280 * 4(bytes per pixel), just over 4 MB, not 619kb. That times 8 images is 32MB.

619KB many be the compressed size on disk but when rendered it must be the full size.

(BTW, "b" is bits, "B" is bytes)

Comment: I see. Thanks, I didn't realise that the size was so large when rendered! My issue would be then how best to approach having a full size bitmap background on a device with a high resolution declared in the xml layout file rather than programatically? i understand that I can use different dpi images in the various drawable folders for varying devices, but surely if the image is going to be used to cover the entire screen, it has to be quite large anyway and thus take up a fair chunk of memory?

Answer (score 0):

An image of 800x1280 is not small!! And having 8 only add to the problem. As your images are in pre-set, you should scale them to their respectful sizes using and put them in their respectful drawable folders ir mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and so on.